# Get all Value of Form Field

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get All data that are in form field once time
I have 60 field in my form
is there any way to collect theme Together؟

Comment: What do you mean by "once time"? 
Collect them together? You mean you want to concat them all in one string?

Comment: explain a bit more & show some code.

Comment: Are you using a JS framework or just vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery:

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var data = new FormData(form);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.send(data);
```

**jQuery:**

```
var queryString = $('#form-id').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in PHP all the requests are stored in an array named $_REQUEST[]
if you use print_r() function on it you will see all the form fields in it.

Comment: `$_POST` or `$_GET` rather than `$_REQUEST` should be used to separate things out a bit

Comment: yah that's true